# Solving non-linear ordinary differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis

> I am attempting to solve the differential equation:
> $$(y')^2 = 1 $$ with the initial condition $y(0)=0$

By moving into the Laplace domain we get:

\begin{align*}s^{2}Y(s)^{2} &= \frac{1}{s}\\Y(s)^{2} &= \frac{1}{s^3}\\Y(s) &= \pm\frac{1}{s^{3/2}}\\ \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)!Y(s) &= \pm\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)!}{s^{3/2}}\\\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\right)\cdot Y(s) &=\pm\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)!}{s^{3/2}}.\end{align*}

which gives 2 solutions:

\begin{align*}Y(s) &= \frac{2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)!}{\sqrt{\pi}s^{3/2}},\\Y(s) &= -\frac{2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)!}{\sqrt{\pi}s^{3/2}}.\end{align*}

Now returning to the time domain,

$$y(t) =\pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} t^{1/2}.$$

Did I solve it correctly?

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding of the Laplace transform, but you can also check to see if your final answer does the job.

Comment: @Aruralreader which is?

Comment: $y=c\pm x{}{}{}$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews you are correct.I realized it cant be my solution.

Comment: The transform of a square is not the square of the transform.

Comment: This is the equivalent of using a bulldozer to remove a weed and then missing the weed entirely.

Comment: Use $a^2=1 \implies a^2-1=0 \implies (a-1)(a+1)=0$ You have to solve two DE.

Answer (score 1):

As others said in the comments of your post, the Laplace transform does not commute with non linear operations such as squaring the function.

The equation can be rewritten as $y' = \pm 1$ which has many weak solutions (the $\pm$ depends on $t$):

If $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ is a measurable set and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure, the continuous function
\begin{equation}
y_A(t)=2\,\text{sgn}(t)\lambda\left(A\cap (0,t)\right)-t
\end{equation}
satisfies $y_A(0) = 0$ and in the sense of the distributions
\begin{equation}
y_A'= \mathbf{1}_A - \mathbf{1}_{A^c}
\end{equation}
Hence $(y_A')^2 = 1$ a.e.